# Is a colon-prefixed branch name some kind of alias for git push <remote-name> --delete <remote-branch-name>?

Tags: git, version-control

Is running a command like `$ git push origin :remote-branch` a shortcut for `git push <remote-name> --delete <remote-branch-name>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. From `man git-push`:

The format is `git push <repository> <refspec>`, with `<refspec>` described as follow:

> ```
> <refspec>
>        Specify what destination ref to update with what source object. 
>        The format of a <refspec> parameter is an optional plus +, followed
>        by the source object <src>, followed by a colon :, followed by
>        the destination ref <dst>.
> ```

Then:

> Pushing an empty `<src>` allows you to delete the `<dst>` ref from the remote repository.

Comment: What's a refspec?

Comment: @leeand00 A refspec is the string that comes after the `<repository>` part of a `git push` or `git fetch`. padawin's answer quotes the description of what goes into a refspec: an optional leading plus sign, then two names (such as branch names) separated by a colon (`:`) character. Refspecs can be reduced from here but the meaning of a reduced refspec is different in `git fetch` and `git push`.